# Ruby Voice Recognition Libraries

Tags: ruby, cross-platform, voice-recognition

Are there any voice recognition libraries built entirely in Ruby or in cross-platform languages that have Ruby implementations (i.e Java)?

Preferably something that doesn't take a lot of code to start using.

Answer (score 5):

[Sphinx 4](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/) is a speech recognition library written in Java that you can [script via JRuby](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby).